# DisplayFormat not working with Nullable<DateTime>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to format some DateTimes in MVC but the DisplayFormat is not being applied to the Nullable object and I can't figure out why. It worked perfectly fine on CreatedDateTime but not LastModifiedDateTime

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yy hh:mm tt}")]
public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yy hh:mm tt}")]
public Nullable<DateTime> LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
```

Below is the View

```
   <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CreatedDateTime)
        <br />
        @Html.Raw(TimeAgo.getStringTime(Model.CreatedDateTime))
    </div>
    @if (Model.LastModifiedDateTime.HasValue)
    { 
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastModifiedDateTime)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastModifiedDateTime)
        <br />
            @Html.Raw(TimeAgo.getStringTime(Model.LastModifiedDateTime.Value)) By: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastModifiedBy)
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: Does it fail if you use `DateTime?` instead of `Nullable<DateTime>`?

Comment: Changing it to DateTime? has no effect.

Comment: @TyCobb `DateTime?` and `Nullable<DateTime>` are identical.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understood your intentions correct (I hope I did), then you can have a display template for Nullable by placing your template in `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/DateTime.cshtml` and define it like the following:

```
@model System.DateTime?
@Html.Label("", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yy hh:mm tt") : string.Empty)
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT**

You can have multiple Display Templates for the same type and specify which one to use by name so let's say you have:

- `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Name1.cshtml`
- `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Name2.cshtml`

You can then call them like:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastModifiedDateTime, "Name1")
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastModifiedDateTime, "Name2")
```

Comment: This resolved the problem but what if I want DateTimes to display differently in different places?

Comment: This the best "workaround" for now, thanks. But really some kind of extension is needed to do this generically for the whole application and support the existing data annotation attributes. But I'm going to check MVC 5 first to see if Microsoft already implemented that into the core. I use nullable types a lot, it's a core requirement from my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I think most simple way to format nullable `DateTime` is to use `ValueFor` method:

```
@Html.ValueFor(m => m.CreatedDateTime , "{0:MM/dd/yy hh:mm tt}")
@Html.ValueFor(m => m.LastModifiedDateTime , "{0:MM/dd/yy hh:mm tt}")
```

When using `ValueFor` method with `TimeSpan` or `Nullable<TimeSpan>`, colon character ":" has to be escaped:

```
@Html.ValueFor(m => m.MyTimeSpan, "{0:hh':'mm}")
```